# How to get dropdown changed value from in jquery to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code

```
$(function(){
    $('#dropdown_name').change(function(){
        var V = $('#dropdown_name').val();
        var T = $('#dropdown_name :selected').text();
    });
});
```

I want to send `V` and `T`'s value below function

```
function xyz()
{
    a = V;
    b = T;
    alert(a);
    alert(b);
}
```

In Function `xyz`, I have to call many function so I don't want, it take as parameter of `xyz` function. So how can I get data in another way when I will select a dropdown then it will display alert(a and b) that value and text of dropdown.

How to solve it, please any suggestion.

Comment: You don't want to pass the values as arguments to the function because you are calling other functions? How does this make sense? I don't see any reason *not* to pass them as arguments. It would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont want to pass as parameters you would likely need to define the variables in a scope available to all functions that will use the variables.

```
var V,T;
$(function(){
    $('#dropdown_name').change(function(){
    V = $('#dropdown_name').val();
    T = $('#dropdown_name :selected').text();
    xyz();
    });
});

function xyz(){
    alert(V); alert(T)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use global variables instead:

```
function xyz()
{
    a = window.V;
    b = window.T;
    alert(a);
    alert(b);
}
```

You will call the function like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('#dropdown_name').change(function(){
    window.V = $('#dropdown_name').val();
    window.T = $('#dropdown_name :selected').text();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use global values too

```
var V = ""; 
var T = "";
$(function(){
    $('#dropdown_name').change(function(){
        V = $('#dropdown_name').val();
        T = $('#dropdown_name :selected').text();
    });
});
I want to send V and T's value below function

function xyz()
{
    a = V;
    b = T;
    alert(a);
    alert(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call your function instead of the anonymous callback on change like if you have fol markup

```
<select>
    <option value=""> select </option>
    <option value="2">SO</option>
    <option value="3">google</option>
</select>
```

js

```
function callback(e){
    console.log($(e.target).val());

}

$(function(){
 $("select").change(callback);
});
```

you can replace the callback function with `xyz`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pEW4t/)

Answer (score 1):

Call xyz from the change event and assign the variables in xyz.

```
$("#dropdown_name").change(function() {
    xyz();
});

function xyz() {
    var a = $("#dropdown_name option:selected").val();
    alert(a);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D48FY/